# Accessing HttpContext while processing a T4 Template

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, t4, template-engine, httpcontext

We have a web-application that uses T4 templates to render pages.
Pages can contain simple things like text etcetera, but they can also contain custom made modules.
These modules rely on the `HttpContext.Current`.

However, the T4 Template is processed in a thread/domain different than my webapplication. And that’s why I cannot access the `HttpContext.Current` in that process.

I tried to add a property for the HttpContext to the modules, which is set in the pre processing of the template. This introduces a new problem;
The T4 engine requires all classes used by the page to be `[Serialized]`. This is no problem, except for the System.Web.HttpContext class which cannot be serialized.

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException:  The type
>   System.Web.HttpContext in assembly System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a is not marked
>   serializable.

So, in order to solve the `SerializationExeption` we’d add `[NonSerialized]` attribute to our property.

```
[NonSerialized]
protected HttpContext _context = null;
public HttpContext Context
{
    get
    {
        return _context;
    }
    set
    {
        _context = value;
    }
}
```

But by the time the template is deserialized and processed, the Context is `null` ofcourse, so I get a `NullReferenceException` in my module.

Is there a way I can access the current `HttpContext` in code called from the template engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also send this question to Microsoft, and there is a very simple solution for it.

In the custom EngineHost there is a function `ProvideTemplatingAppDomain`. You have to make sure your Engine returns `AppDomain.CurrentDomain`.

In this way, the template will be compiled and ran in the same domain as your webrequest.